# Hooking up a battery to a BLE beacon

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, bluetooth-low-energy

I am looking to add a battery to [this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Silicon-Laboratories/BLE112-A-V1/?qs=ScTHCgOnmkJ6UytbwX03ig%3D%3D&gclid=CjwKCAjwoKDXBRAAEiwA4xnqvxVxq-QNXX8Xo9HoOS4jJLmC5IuPF-tAq3TlW5sKWS4HZ1gu_P_v9BoC6RwQAvD_BwE) BLE beacon with as few parts as possible.

In their product's [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/368/Bluegiga_Technologies_BLE112_Datasheet-1203259.pdf) they include a section on an example schematic for adding a battery (included below). My issue is

1. The picture is far too blurry to see what is going on
2. The process of adding a battery seems very complex

Given a 3 V coin battery, what are the steps to powering this BLE beacon?

[image]

Comment: You should be aware that it's possible to _zoom_ in a PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zoom in the pdf, and the text is not rasterized so it's clear. Here's the application schematic:
[image]

According to the datasheet all you need is the coin cell, and a couple of capacitors. Forget about the optional DC/DC converter for now. That just reduces the power consumption a little bit.

You need C15 connected in parallel with the coin cell. Then C6,C3, and C5 as close to the device as possible (those are decoupling caps). That's it. If you omit the DC/DC converter, then the coin cell connects directly to AVDD, DVDD_USB, and DVDD.